# What colors does Graphicsmagik support?

Tags: graphicsmagick

I'm using Graphicsmagik from the command-line and I want to specify RGB values.

(How) can I do this? What colors / color formats does Graphicsmagik support?

Answer (score 0):

Graphicsmagik supports hex values and some [named colors](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/color.html), although you can add your own with a [config file](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#file).